# Get or Else None Scala toBoolean

Tags: scala

I have the follow function in Scala:

```
def boolOrNone(n: NodeSeq): Option[Boolean] = {
    Some(Try((n.text.toBoolean)).getOrElse(None)) 
}
```

The problem is that it won't compile because it returns type `Option[Any]` which makes sense but I need this method to return `Option[Boolean]` What is the best way to return a none type if the `n.text.toBoolean` fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you just want `Try(n.text.toBoolean).toOption`